# iPad: SplitView does not rotate

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have the following setup:

- A subclass of `UISplitViewController` that creates the master and detail view controllers in the constructor.
- Master and Detail view controllers that both override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return `YES`.
- Detail view controller implements the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` protocol and deals with the popover.

I am observing two weird issues that might be interrelated:

1. When the split view comes up (in portrait mode - default on simulator), the Master view is    visible. It should not be.
2. When I rotate the simulator, the view does not "right" itself.

My `UISplitViewController` subclass does not override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. However, both master and details view controllers do and return `YES`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Is this a simulator bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who lands here: This was happening because my split view controller's view was not the root. This is absolutely required.

Comment: Sorry, I am having the same problem but I don't know what do you mean with wasn't root. My ios level is really basic. Could you explain what can I do here?

Comment: It has been a while. In my recollection, root view is the first or basic view that gets created when an application is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the interface orientations you want to support. They can be found in the project settings under the Summary tab.

Comment: can you provide a reference ?

Comment: I would provide a screenshot but my reputation isn't high enough yet.