# UISplitViewController rotations

Tags: ios, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

How does a UISplitViewController know when it has rotated so that it can trigger the appropriate behavior with managing its views? Is there some way I can manually trigger it myself? I have a split view controller owning a view that is not at the root of my hierarchy, so it is not getting the rotation events that (I think) normally allow it to handle rotation behavior.

Comment: You exactly need to make your own custom controller and catch/send necessary events from root to the sub–controllers. Please check out my [custom UISplitViewController](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html). It really does exactly what you want but you use it as a basis or just as idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to implement UISplitViewController delegate which is:

// Landscape mode

– splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:

// Portrait mode

– splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:

Since the masterView (left) will show/hide accordingly when the rotation occurs, I found this is more effective compared to handling the orientation changes if each view

Answer (score 0):

I guess [UiSplitViewController doesn't autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734016/uisplitviewcontroller-doesnt-autorotate) and 
[iPad: SplitView does not rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770159/ipad-splitview-does-not-rotate) pretty much say that unless the controller's view is the root view, it won't work.  Oh apple.

Answer (score 0):

You could sign up for notifications of orientation changing, make sure you have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation set to YES for the rotations you want to support as well.